# why the output are not the same?

Tags: c++

I checked both by compiler that:

The output of this is 10

```
    int count = 0; 
    for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i){ 
            count=++count;
    }
    cout << count;
```

I don't get why the output of this(++count becomes count++) is 0

```
    int count = 0; 
    for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i){ 
            count=count++;
    }
    cout << count;
```

Comment: Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With

```
        count=++count;
```

and

```
        count=count++;
```

both programs run into undefined behaviour as you are modifying `count` without an intervening sequence point. Note that `=` operator doesn't introduce a sequence point.

Obligatory read on UB ;-)

**[Undefined Behavior and Sequence Points in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)**